# Is this lock free design thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, atomic

In different threads I do the following:

*shared variable:*

```
std::shared_ptr<Data> dataPtr;
std::atomic<int> version_number;
```

Thread1, the producer receive new data and do

```
dataPtr.reset(newdata);
version_number++;
```

Other threads, consumers are doing:

```
int local_version=0;
std::shared_ptr<Data> localPtr;
while(local_version!=version_number)
 localPtr=dataPtr;
 ...operation on my_ptr...
 localPtr.reset();
 local_version=version_number.load();
```

Here I know that the consumers might skip some version, if they are processing data and new updates keep going, thats fine by me, i dont need them to process all versions, just the last available to them.
My question is, is this line atomic :

```
localPtr=dataPtr;
```

Will I always obtain the last version of what is in dataPtr or will this be cached or might lead to anything wrong in my design ?

Thks.

Comment: [atomic_load](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr: yes. `my_ptr = dataPtr` is thread-safe.

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment)
>   can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr
>   without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies
>   and share ownership of the same object.

There is no guarantee though that the version you think you're loading will be the one you will be loading; the setting of the pointer by the producer and the the upping of the version number are not an `atomic` operation and neither is the reading of the pointer by the consumer and the updating of the version number by the consumer.

Comment: Do you mean in term of ordering, the producer could increment the counter before updating the pointer for example ?

Comment: __different instance__, in this case `dataPtr` is a same instance used by multiple threads therefore it is not thread-safe

Comment: @user2164703: No, consider this ordering: (1) produce dataptr (4) consume version (2) produce version (3) produce dataptr (5) consume dataptr (6) produce version

Comment: Thx Ben; that's what I meant: there is no ordering. @Bryan: no, the consumer have their own versions of the shared_ptr, my_ptr.

Comment: I am saying `my_ptr = dataPtr` is _not_ thread-safe. you need to use `atomic_load`

Comment: Sorry havee, i renamed my_ptr to localPtr and added the declaration for the question to be clearer. You can rename it in your answer/comment

Comment: The C++ reference sais otherwise.

Comment: @user2164703: thx, it was obvious to me but now it's even better.

Comment: I just edit your answer to highlight my point. again, use [atomic_load](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: @BryanChen: You're wrong, though.  The data race comes from the concurrent write, not from multiple reads of the shared_ptr.  See the last paragraph of `[[util.smartptr.shared]]`

Answer (score 3):

As haavee points out, multiple threads can safely simultaneously do

```
localPtr = dataPtr;
```

because the shared variable is only read, and the shared metadata block which is updated in the process has a special thread safety guarantee.

However, there is a race between

```
dataPtr.reset(newdata); // in producer, a WRITE to the shared_ptr
localPtr = dataPtr;     // in consumer, an access to the same shared_ptr
```

so this design is NOT thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears rather constructed to me. What would be the benefit if a random number of consumers looked at the same data? (This is what would happen in your code, though in a technically thread-safe manner.)

If you want to have a first consumer takes data others don't kind of scheme, you might want to atomically swap the dataPtr for a empty() shared_ptr from each consumer. Then after the swap the consumer checks for what he got to be non-empty and does the computation. All other consumers who did the same, will get an empty() shared ptr after their respective swap.

After removing the the version number from your code, you got a lock free- use-once producer consumer scheme.

```
std::shared_ptr<Data> dataPtr;

void Producer()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Data> newOne = std::shared_ptr<Data>::make_shared();
    std::atomic_exchange(dataPtr, newOne);
}

// called from multiple threads
void Consumer()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Data> mine;
    std::atomic_exchange(mine,dataPtr);
    if( !mine.empty() )
    {  // compute, using mine. Only one thread is lucky for any given Data instance stored by producer.
    }
}
```

EDIT:
As it turns out from documentation found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), shared_ptr::swap() is not atomic. Adjusted the code accordingly.
EDIT2: Producer corrected. One more reason not to use that stuff in the first place.

For the use case you describe, when you really don't care if some consumers miss something now and then, here a complete implementation, which packs the version number together with the data. The template allows to use that for other types as well. Maybe with a few more constructors, deletes etc. added...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>


template <class _T>
class Versioned
{
    _T m_data;
    uint32_t m_version;
    static std::atomic<uint32_t> s_next;
public: 
    Versioned(_T & data)
        : m_data(data)
        , m_version(s_next.fetch_add(1UL))
    {}
    ~Versioned()
    {

    }
    const _T & Data() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }
    uint32_t Version() const
    {
        return m_version;
    }
};

template <class _T>
std::atomic<uint32_t> Versioned<_T>::s_next;

typedef Versioned<std::string> VersionedString;

static volatile bool s_running = true;
static std::shared_ptr<VersionedString> s_dataPtr;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::thread> consumers;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        consumers.push_back(std::thread([]()
        { 
            uint32_t oldVersion = ~0UL;
            std::shared_ptr<VersionedString> mine; 
            while (s_running)
            {
                mine = std::atomic_load(&s_dataPtr);
                if (mine)
                {
                    if (mine->Version() != oldVersion)
                    {
                        oldVersion = mine->Version();

                        // No lock taken for cout -> chaotic output possible.
                        std::cout << mine->Data().c_str();
                    }
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        std::shared_ptr<VersionedString> next = std::make_shared<VersionedString>(std::string("Hello World!"));
        std::atomic_store(&s_dataPtr, next);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    s_running = false;
    for (auto& t : consumers)
    {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @BenVoigt It would only race if swap were not atomic. The consumers "race" who gets the job to be done. But it is not a race where one data instance can be processed more than once. There is a chance, that 1 Data item is not processed at all, but that is what he wanted.

Comment: swap is not thread-safe. use [atomic_exchange](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/swap is as shallow a documentation as it can get. My assumption was that shared_ptr<>::swap() does an atomic exchange. If it does not, std::atomic_exchange() needs to be used. This is one of the reasons why I prefer to use native functions for my concurrency and not those c++11 files. Then at least I know what happens.

Comment: you can only assume things are not thread-safe. not otherwise.

Comment: Thks but different consumers consume the same data, because they are not homogeneous consumers, they are in fact doing different things with the same data (imagine different model for the same inputs).

Comment: Still races.  The producer needs to use an atomic operation also.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually your "lock free" scheme is just a waste of time and CPU.

If you don't care about losing intermediate versions, simply have your producer limit its output to a frequency the consumers can cope with, and use a shared queue or any of the tried and proved inter-task communication mechanisms to pass data packets around.

Real-time systems are all about guaranteeing responsiveness, and a good design tries to put a reasonable cap on that instead of burning CPU for the sake of coolness.

C++11 and the new "non blocking" whim of fashion are doing so much harm by luring every man and his dog into believing a couple of atomic variables will solve every synchronization problem. As a matter of fact, they won't.

Comment: There are valid situations where actually it makes sense to go for lock free designs. Whenever it is not a "reactive" system but rather some number crunching application. With high frequency context switches you soon have not much left for the calculations. What he tries to do here makes sense if this is some kind of side-scenario within such a computation task. The threads are not spinning idly but do the "real" work. See for example a state of the art chess program and think about how it would perform if you made it "event driven". https://stockfishchess.org/download/

Comment: Indeed there might be rare cases where custom-made lock free designs are the solution. In that case there is no need to package them into a general purpose synchronization object, they are just a part of a carefully balanced global software design. And how many programmers out there are expert enough to design a chess program in the first place?

Comment: Actually after posting the above, I did have a look at the sources and...I am disappointed :)